# How to setup Celery to talk ssl to Azure Redis Instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, redis, celery

Using the great answer to "[How to configure celery-redis in django project on microsoft azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616701/how-to-configure-celery-redis-in-django-project-on-microsoft-azure)", I can configure Celery to use Azure Redis Cache using the **non-ssl port, 6379**, using the following Python code:

```
from celery import Celery
# This one works
url = 'redis://:<access key>@<my server>.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0'
# I want to use a url that specifies ssl like one of the following:
# url = 'redis://:<my key>=@<my server>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0'
# url = 'redis://:<my key>@<my server>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0?ssl=True'
app = Celery('tasks', broker=url)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

However, I would like to have celery use ssl and communicate on **port 3380 using ssl** to the Azure Redis Cache.  If I change the port to 6380, I get an "Error while reading from socket" after a few minutes of waiting after running the following command:

`celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -Q "celery" -Ofair`

Does anyone know how to configure this, on the Celery or Azure side, so that I can have celery communicate on the default **3380** port on Azure Redis Cache using **ssl**?

I am using the latest version of Celery (4.0.2)

Note that code like the following works with no problem when connecting directly from a **Linux client** (on Azure) using port 3380 and ssl using Python's redis library:

```
import redis
redis.StrictRedis(host='<my host>.redis.cache.windows.net', port=6380, db=0, password='<my key>', ssl=True)
```

Comment: Did either of the answers fix this for you?

Comment: this answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088277/1360476 @duck

Answer (score 10):

It's already possible using `rediss://` instead `redis://`.

```
url = 'rediss://:<access key>@<my server>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0'
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be the accepted answer now.
Since celery team fixed issue 2833, you may not need to use `broker_use_ssl` and `redis_backend_use_ssl` configuration parameters anymore.

Please note that in order to make it work the exact connection string is this one:

`url = 'rediss://:<access key>@<my server>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0?ssl_cert_reqs=required'`

See documentation at https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#redis-backend-settings

Answer (score 3):

For the broker, you should be able to set the [broker_use_ssl](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_use_ssl) configuration option.

For the backend, the option [redis_backend_use_ssl](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.1.0/userguide/configuration.html#redis-backend-use-ssl) was made available in the 4.1.0 release.

The ability to enable SSL via the URL isn't available yet: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2833

Also, note that [official support for Windows was dropped in 4.0](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#removed-features). However, you might be able to get it working by following the instructions at https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4082