# Connect Azure Web App to Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: python, azure, flask, redis, celery

How can I connect the Azure Cache for Redis to the Flask WebApp that uses celery to perform some asynchronous tasks? Whenever I try to connect via Webjob, it would say unable to connect to redis.

I also tried enter this `celery inspect ping -b redis://{password}@{redis_service_name}.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0` from this post [How to configure celery-redis in django project on microsoft azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616701/how-to-configure-celery-redis-in-django-project-on-microsoft-azure) but i would get `Connection Failure: If this issue persists, ensure your computer's firewall and proxy settings allow outbound TCP traffic to port 10225. Using the firewall feature on your cache may also block connections from the console if your IP address has not been whitelisted`

Comment: Could it be that you just simply use wrong port? Redis typically listens on 6379. Also an advice - do not use names that clash with existing modules/packages (app.celery) you will sooner or later end up with a problem. `project_name.app_name` makes much more sense (change project_name and app_name to match your current work).

Comment: tried both ports, didn't work

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure but I assume it has something similar to AWS SecurityGroups - you need to allow traffic to the Redis server...

Comment: Where that port number 10225 comes from??

Answer (score 5):

If there is no special rule in the firewall, this error should not occur. In general, there are special firewall settings in company networks, so access problems can occur. In this case, you need to allow the firewall to port 10225 outbound.
You can test it on a different network using Redis console on Azure to see if it's firewall-related.

using company network with firewall rule
[image: using company network with firewall rule]

other network without firewall rule
[image]

Comment: Yes, I disconnected from the VPN on my laptop, and it worked. It was probably a proxy/firewall behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching your network to work temporarily. This is a network specific issue and the port used to connect to Redis server is blocked and needs to be opened.

Comment: This has saved me, thanks! My corporate network uses set of VPNs and utilizes them automatically according to availability/throughput. It seems that some of them do have a firewall and some do not. Right now when I am receiving the error described in a question, I am just changing the VPN gateway and I'm done. Thanks again!